# How to check multi dates from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get result from two tables, one table have data and another one have time. My table look like this.

CheckInOut :

```
USERID  int Unchecked
CHECKTIME   datetime    Unchecked
CHECKTYPE   varchar(1)  Checked
```

Data :

```
84  2015-06-16 11:15:17.000 I
84  2015-06-16 20:42:52.000 O
84  2015-06-17 11:04:43.000 I
84  2015-06-17 20:59:32.000 O
84  2015-06-18 10:35:05.000 I
84  2015-06-18 16:37:14.000 O
84  2015-06-18 16:38:56.000 O
84  2015-06-20 10:34:15.000 I
```

`ShiftName`:

```
ShiftName StartTime EndTime
---------------------------
Morning   9:00    6:00
After     12:00   9:00
```

`EmpShift`:

```
EmpNo  StartDate    EndDate      ShiftName
------------------------------------------
84  2015-04-01  2015-06-17  Store
191 2015-05-01  2015-06-10  Store
126 2015-04-01  2015-06-10  Store
105 2015-04-01  2015-06-10  Morning
103 2015-05-01  2015-06-30  Morning
106 2015-06-13  2015-06-18  AfterNoon
86  2015-06-01  2015-06-30  Morning
84  2015-06-18  2015-07-18  Morning
```

In my case empid 84 has two shifts in same month. But when I am executing my query it checks only first one. I mean it return only Morning for all the row.

Please check my query.

```
Select  
    EmpShift.EmpID,
    EmpShift.ShiftName,
    EmpShift.StartDate,
    EmpShift.EndDate,
    Convert(varchar(10), CHECKINOUT.CheckTime, 121) As WorkDate,
    convert(char(5), Min(CHECKINOUT.CheckTime), 108) As CheckTime,
    CHECKINOUT.CheckType,
    CHECKINOUT.CheckTime
From    
    EmpShift
Inner Join 
    CHECKINOUT On EmpShift.EmpID = CHECKINOUT.USERID 
Where  
    ((EmpShift.EmpID = 100) AND
     ((EmpShift.StartDate Between '2015-06-01' AND '2015-06-30') AND
     (EmpShift.EndDate Between  '2015-06-01' AND '2015-06-30')))
Group By 
     EmpShift.EmpID, 
     Convert(varchar(10), CHECKINOUT.CheckTime, 121),convert(char(5), CHECKINOUT.CheckTime, 108),
     EmpShift.EmpID, EmpShift.ShiftName, 
     EmpShift.StartDate, EmpShift.EndDate,
     CHECKINOUT.CheckType, CHECKINOUT.CheckTime
```

Comment: its a table name , getting the employee in and out details.

Comment: And also the reason why you're not getting the expected results?

Comment: i am suspecting this line ,  Where  ((EmpShift.EmpID=100) AND
     ((EmpShift.StartDate Between '2015-06-01' AND '2015-06-30') AND
     (EmpShift.EndDate Between  '2015-06-01' AND '2015-06-30')))

Comment: yea i tried that way too

Comment: The problem you have is that your shifts and CHECKINOUT are not linked in any way, so you get all the shifts for all the days

Comment: Try remove **convert(char(5), CHECKINOUT.CheckTime, 108)** from group by

Comment: JamesZ-> you are correct its not linked , but i am not using the shift directly here. you can suggest me any solution, if this is the reason.

Comment: Can you post data of CHECKINOUT so we can help you better.

Comment: vasin-> i post that one too,

Comment: With current data, there will be no result for emp84 as StartDate and EndDate are out of range for your filter.

Comment: its only the sample data i posted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're after:

```
Select  EmpShift.EmpID,
            EmpShift.ShiftName,
            EmpShift.StartDate,
            EmpShift.EndDate,
            CHECKINOUT.CheckType,
            CHECKINOUT.CheckTime
    From    EmpShift
            Inner Join CHECKINOUT On EmpShift.EmpID=CHECKINOUT.USERID 
            and CHECKINOUT.CheckTime >= EmpShift.StartDate 
            and CHECKINOUT.CheckTime < EmpShift.EndDate
    Where  (--(EmpShift.EmpID=84) AND
     ((EmpShift.StartDate < '2015-06-30') AND
     (EmpShift.EndDate > '2015-06-01')))
```

This has now a link between the dates in EmpShift and CHECKINOUT.

You can test this in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f5098/3). I created CHECKINOUT with 6 rows, I and O row for 3 separate days

Comment: But this code returns empty for me. No rows return.

Comment: Since that works fine in SQL Fiddle, I guess it's again because of CHECKINOUT. Maybe you should now include that into your example? Also, your datatypes are correct and you're not storing dates as varchar, right?

Comment: Since your selected columns includes CheckTime, the group by and min won't work anyway, it's going to just list the rows

Comment: included now.. please check the question. still its confusing why its showing only one shift. really straight forward query.

Comment: But his problem is he is getting fewer rows, not duplication

Comment: What's the data you're using? My SQL Fiddle had that exact structure and it works. Also, the EmpNo vs EmpId was just a typo in the question, you don't have 2 different columns in EmpShift, right?

Comment: both are int. updated data again in the question. its returning the data , but the issue is its not correct.

Comment: Yes now the problem is that your new data is not anymore inside the data range that you have in your SQL (and had in the previous example for user id 100)

Comment: its attendance result , i have record until today. what i posted that one only sample to show you , how its look like.

Comment: Changed new SQL Fiddle link to the answer, now that fetches all the shifts that overlap with the date range, not just the ones that start and end inside it -- and now there's again correct data

Comment: What you made the changes ? you remove the workdate and timenow?

Comment: I changed the start / end date criteria for fetching the shifts

Comment: JamesZ thank you very much. its really a big help. you find it. thanks alot.